# Why this if statement fails with undefined local variable or method depending on the arguments order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to understand why I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method ` current_user' for #<#<Class:0x007fc58d3b9ed0>:0x007fc58d4e92b0>
```

In my slim template I've got:

```
- if  current_user.admin? || current_user == @user 
  do something .....
```

It's an old app an usually only the admins dig enough to render this template. And when they do `current_user.admin?` part is working and no error is thrown.
Today a user land to the template and `current_user == @user` should have return `true` and render the template because the user was legit but I got this error instead.

After some resolving attempts I figure out that if I inverted the arguments everything works as expected:

```
- if  current_user == @user  || current_user.admin?
```

I don't understand why I got the error and why the inversion of the arguments make this works?

UPDATE full error trace:

```
F, [2017-06-09T10:07:45.191191 #87199] FATAL -- :
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method ` current_user' for #<#<Class:0x007fec49b70510>:0x007fec4e3a69b0>
Did you mean?  current_user
               @current_user):
    15:           =t('users.actions.new_user')
    16:
    17:       - if params[:controller] == 'admin/users' && params[:action] == 'show'
    18:         - if current_user.admin? || current_user.id == @user.id
    19:
    20:           li
    21:             = link_to main_app.edit_admin_user_path(@user), class: "leftMenuContent__listItem--sublink waves-effect waves-hsBlue" do
  app/views/layouts/admin/left_nav_content/_users.html.slim:18:in `_app_views_layouts_admin_left_nav_content__users_html_slim___2298613765678674655_70326381737720'
  app/views/layouts/admin/_left_content_navbar.html.slim:53:in `_app_views_layouts_admin__left_content_navbar_html_slim__3826854879423528297_70326437315280'
  app/views/layouts/admin/application.html.slim:43:in `_app_views_layouts_admin_application_html_slim___31832608430187073_70326348296780'
```

**Update 2:**

After digging I realize that the error was gone after a complete rewrite of the line. As mentioned in the comments I think the error is due to a "non real white space", this happened sometimes in some editors.

Comment: I'm not sure why they error is what it is, but the reverse of the arguments can make sense due to if the first argument in an OR is satisfied, the second argument will not even be checked due to the output already reading true. So current_user.admin? is probably causing you the error in both cases, just not being checked in the second case if current_user == @user returns true

Comment: Hum that would make sense! But admin is just a boolean field in the db and having it to false or nil should just return false when using current_user.admin? When admins go there the current_user.admin? works shouldn't it throws the same error if it was really undefined?

Comment: But I agreed to your analyse, current_user.admin? seems in fault and that explains why reversing the arguments makes the render to work.

Comment: Could you add the error trace, see if that brings anything to light?

Comment: Yes I'll,  but I think the error was due to a "white space typo" as I was making some tests, rewriting it from scratch and/or pasting from my own question in SO lead to the fact that the error was gone. It's not the first time the editor "White space" is not a real "space".

Comment: I just posted the full trace but I think this the "real" error came from what I called the white space typo.

Comment: Down voters, can you explain why you think the question is not legit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the results of short circuit algorithm:

In an `||` statement if the first argument is true, it doesn't bother checking the second.

In an `&&` statement if the first argument is false, it doesn't bother checking the second.

It looks like something in `admin?` is attempting to call `current_user` function or variable that is not defined in the scope of `admin?`

Comment: Yes you pointed out the same thing as @EastonBornemeier did. And I agree that this explains why the reverse make things working. But now this doesn't explain why an admin didn't get the error. As mentioned above, admin is just a boolean field in the db. I'm still digging to see if I missed something.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because even if the error was caused by a typo, the short circuit of the if statement explains why reversing the order seems to solve the problem.